# Tomcat deployment works but getting 404

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have a maven application. When I am doing tomcat deployment, it works. I am able to see index.html. But when I try to call any rest api in the service, it shows 404. 
For example, if /xyz is my context, http://localhost:8080/xyz works but
http://localhost:8080/xyz/status or any other rest api gives a 404.

I am using intellij community edition(Smart Tomcat plugin).

Comment: could you double check the context given in your controller? Also, the tomcat logs probably show the URLs that are getting registered.